# Low download speed without proxy

Tags: c#, proxy, fiddler

I have written some code that invoke method **webClient.DownloadString**. When I ran my programe profiler show that this method takes 98% of time in the program (not processor time), and download speed is too slow (about 10% of maximal download speed).

When I run my program with **Fiddler** download speed increases to 75% - 90% of maximal download speed.

Where is my error? And How can I increase download speed of my application?

Here is my code.

```
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("1251");
        wc.Proxy = null;
        HtmlDocument html = new HtmlDocument();
        html.LoadHtml(wc.DownloadString("http://some-site.com/" + htmlUrl));
        var c1 = html.GetElementbyId("content");
        foreach (var c2 in c1.ChildNodes.Where(c => c.Name == "div"))
        {
            foreach (var c3 in c2.ChildNodes.Where(c => c.Name == "a"))
            {
                var leftIndex = c3.InnerText.IndexOf('(');
                var rightIndex = c3.InnerText.LastIndexOf(')');
                var id = c3.InnerText.Substring(0, leftIndex - 1).Replace(" ", "");
                var name = c3.InnerText.Substring(leftIndex + 1, rightIndex - leftIndex - 1);

                SaveInDB(int.Parse(id), name);
            }
        }
```

I have run it in several threads to increase download speed.

And I tried to use other variants `wc.Proxy = null` or `wc.Proxy = GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy()` or `WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy()` or `wc.Proxy = new WebProxy()`. I always had a low download speed as result.

Turning off **"Automatically detect settings"** on the **"Control Panel"/"Internet Options" -> Connection tab -> LAN settings** also didn't increase download speed.

Answer (score 0):

```
IWebProxy proxy = GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy();
wc.Proxy = proxy;
```